# Android able to fetch google.com , but not any other webpage

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-async-http

I am using [android-async-http](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) to run a simple push notification example. 
The device is able to receive the notification just fine. After it receives the file, I am calling a get request using the above mentioned library:

```
Log.d("TAG", "GOT");
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get("http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=states&format=json", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                // called before request is started
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
                try {
                    String decoded = new String(response, "UTF-8");
                    Log.d("TAG", decoded);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)

                try {
                    String dec = new String(errorResponse, "UTF-8");
                    Log.d("TAG",dec);
                }
                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException q){
                    q.printStackTrace();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
                // called when request is retried
            }
        });
```

In that url should return json, but in my log, I see no messages at all. its all blank, that log.d is never called. But when I change that url to www.google.com, it returns some html (which is google's homepage) . 
I have added

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> ```

to the manifest.

This is my logcat:

> 02-13 21:06:12.189
>   12101-12101/com.example.harshvardhangupta.gcmpleasework D/TAG: GOT
>   02-13 21:06:12.468
>   12101-12101/com.example.harshvardhangupta.gcmpleasework V/AsyncHttpRH:
>   Progress 1310 from 1522 (86%) 02-13 21:06:12.468
>   12101-12101/com.example.harshvardhangupta.gcmpleasework V/AsyncHttpRH:
>   Progress 3333 from 1522 (219%) 02-13 21:06:12.469
>   12101-12101/com.example.harshvardhangupta.gcmpleasework V/AsyncHttpRH:
>   Progress 5238 from 1522 (344%)

Do notice the dotted lines. After @Taylor Courtney's comment, I noticed that the response is coming , but its not being converted to a string from byte array properly

Answer (score 1):

Well, Your AsyncHttpClient ([doc](https://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient.html)) is requesting link which is returning JsonArray ([response](http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=states&format=json)). You should use then JsonHttpResponseHandler ([doc](https://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/JsonHttpResponseHandler.html)) instead.

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get("http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=states&format=json", new JsonHttpResponseHandler("UTF-8") {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess response: " + response.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```